# Meaning of "but if I can't do better, how is it to be helped?"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence

The following is an excerpt from the novel, Jane Eyre. I don't quite understand the meaning of the italicized sentence. Would someone please enlighten me on that?

> "It is a long way to Ireland, Janet, and I am sorry to send my little friend on such weary travels: *but if I can't do better, how is it to be helped?* Are you anything akin to me, do you think, Jane?
>
> I could risk no sort of answer to by this time: my heart was still.
>
> "Because," he said, "I sometimes have a queer feeling with regard to you — especially when you are near me, as now; ...

Comment: _but needs must_

Comment: Lit crit is off-topic.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpreting literary work.

Comment: I think this is more a matter of understanding the language than lit crit.

Comment: As an aside, though: there are idiomatic expressions in the italicized part. What part (word, phrase, expression) did you not understand?

Comment: @Kris, it is not interpreting, just understanding a grammatical construct of *to be helped*

Answer (score 3):

Rochester is suggesting that there is nothing else to be done, given his inability to perform any alternative course of action. One of the meanings of *help* is ‘to remedy, obviate, prevent, cause to be otherwise’.